# Split pandas dataframe based on values in a column using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to split the following dataframe based on column ZZ

```
df = 
        N0_YLDF  ZZ        MAT
    0  6.286333   2  11.669069
    1  6.317000   6  11.669069
    2  6.324889   6  11.516454
    3  6.320667   5  11.516454
    4  6.325556   5  11.516454
    5  6.359000   6  11.516454
    6  6.359000   6  11.516454
    7  6.361111   7  11.516454
    8  6.360778   7  11.516454
    9  6.361111   6  11.516454
```

As output, I want a new `DataFrame` with the `N0_YLDF` column split into 4, one new column for each unique value of `ZZ`. How do I go about this? I can do groupby, but do not know what to do with the grouped object.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

```
gb = df.groupby('ZZ')    
[gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]
```

Comment: Great answer! How do we extract the respective dataframes from gb?

Comment: The method `get_group(x)` returns a new DataFrame object containing only the rows where column `ZZ` == x

Answer (score 41):

There is another alternative as the groupby returns a generator we can simply use a list-comprehension to retrieve the 2nd value (the frame).

```
dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby('ZZ')]
```

Comment: would this one liner work if I'm looking to make specific aggregations to every data frame?

Comment: This one-liner simply stores the dataframes in an array. What you do next is up to you. Maybe have a look at ALollz answer to access keys.

Answer (score 12):

In R there is a dataframe method called split. This is for all the R users out there:

```
def split(df, group):
     gb = df.groupby(group)
     return [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]
```

Comment: shouldn't you put it all into a series? ending with `pd.Series(...)`

Comment: This is amazing.  Is there an easy way to get the key which identifies of the group, so I can return a list of tuples, like ```[ (key, gb.get_group(x) ) for x in gb.group]```?

Comment: I found this, which makes this easy: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513049/get-all-keys-from-groupby-object-in-pandas

Comment: Just to provide an answer to the comment (which is explained in more detail in the link: `[(key, gb.get_group(key)) for key in gb.groups]`

Comment: The same solution but with iterators
`def split(df, group):
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    for g in gb.groups:
        yield gb.get_group(g)`

Answer (score 7):

Store them in a `dict`, which allows you access to the group DataFrames based on the group keys.

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('ZZ')))
d[6]

#    N0_YLDF  ZZ        MAT
#1  6.317000   6  11.669069
#2  6.324889   6  11.516454
#5  6.359000   6  11.516454
#6  6.359000   6  11.516454
#9  6.361111   6  11.516454
```

If you need only a subset of the DataFrame, in this case just the `'NO_YLDF'` Series, you can modify the dict comprehension.

```
d = dict((idx, gp['N0_YLDF']) for idx, gp in df.groupby('ZZ'))
d[6]
#1    6.317000
#2    6.324889
#5    6.359000
#6    6.359000
#9    6.361111
#Name: N0_YLDF, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over unique values and get groups using `loc` or `query`:

```
[df.loc[df['ZZ'] == i] for i in df['ZZ'].unique()]
```

or

```
[df.query('ZZ == @i') for i in df['ZZ'].unique()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to user qwwqwwq answer:

```
gb = df.groupby('ZZ')
df_six = gb.get_group("6") #to create another dataframe with ZZ = 6
df_one = gb.get_group("7") #to create another dataframe with ZZ = 7
```