# How to split dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below

```
A B C
0 a h
0 b i
0 c j
1 d k
1 e l
2 f m
2 g n
```

I would like to split dataframe by df.A

```
A B C
0 a h
0 b i 
0 c j
```

and

```
A B C
1 d k
1 e l
```

and

```
A B C
2 f m
2 g n
```

I tried groupby but It didnt work well. how can I split dataframe to multiple dataframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23691133/1278112)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `dictionary` of `DataFrames` by `dict comprehension`:

```
dfs = {k:v for k, v in df.groupby('A')}
print (dfs)

{0:    A  B  C
0  0  a  h
1  0  b  i
2  0  c  j, 1:    A  B  C
3  1  d  k
4  1  e  l, 2:    A  B  C
5  2  f  m
6  2  g  n}

print (dfs[0])
   A  B  C
0  0  a  h
1  0  b  i
2  0  c  j

print (dfs[1])
   A  B  C
3  1  d  k
4  1  e  l
```

If necessary you can reset index:

```
dfs = {k:v.reset_index(drop=True) for k, v in df.groupby('A')}
print (dfs)
{0:    A  B  C
0  0  a  h
1  0  b  i
2  0  c  j, 1:    A  B  C
0  1  d  k
1  1  e  l, 2:    A  B  C
0  2  f  m
1  2  g  n}

print (dfs[1])
   A  B  C
0  1  d  k
1  1  e  l

print (dfs[2])
   A  B  C
0  2  f  m
1  2  g  n
```

Comment: Good to use different variable, `v` for `df` - `{k: v for k, v in df.groupby('A')}` perhaps? I find to easier to read. `df` could confuse.