# How to get last four days sale count in particular month and first 27 day's sale count?

Tags: python-3.x

How to get each device number sale count and filter who had done a sales more than the first 27 days count(01/Mar/2020 - 27/Mar/2020) < last 4 days count(28/Mar/2020 - 31/Mar/2020).

```
Device_num      Date        sale_type
2344            1/3/2020      BP
2344            12/3/2020     BP
2344            15/3/2020     BP
2344            20/3/2020     BP
2344            28/3/2020     BP
3455            10/3/2020     Retailer
3455            15/3/2020     Retailer
3455            31/3/2020     Retailer 


output table
Device_num  sale_type   1st_27dayssale  Tot_sale last4dayscount
2344          BP             4            5           1           
3455          Retailer       2            3           1
```

Comment: How is the data stored?

Comment: i need to three columns  one is the total sale count groupby Device_num, the second is last four days sale count groupby  Device_num and the third one is first 27 days sale count groupby Device_num

Comment: ...how is it stored? SQL???

Comment: i am seeking python script not SQL script

Comment: ahh sorry @seven_seas. it's stored in CSV format (excel file)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211705/discussion-between-shulaz-shan-and-seven-seas).

Comment: Can you add the expected output and clarify what you want more precisely ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. I updated, I am expecting the output table, not average i need only sale count

Comment: @AlexandreB. small clarification on ur code, I need to get the last three days sales count in each month. How to get that? because each month days count different (i.e if take march 31 days, if take April 30 days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.groupby(["Device_num", "sale_type", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq="m")]).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({"Device_num":  x.name[0],
                         "sale_type": x.name[1],
                         "1st_27dayssale": (x.Date.dt.day <= 27).sum(),
                         "Tot_sale": len(x),
                         "last4dayscount" : (x.Date.dt.day > 27).sum()})) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Explanations:**

1. The dataset is grouped by 3 keys using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

   - The `Device_num` since you want a row for each device num
   - The `sale_type` because we also want a row for each sale_type
   - The current month using [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html). In `pd.grouper`, the argument `key` selects the column used in the grouper and the `freq` stands for the groupby `frequency`. Here we use `m` to group by month. For more details, have a look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646191/pandas-groupby-month-and-year)
2. Then for each above group, we will want to return the 5 expected columns. [`pd.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) let use perform a function to each group. We want our function return:

   - `Device_num`: this a key from the group, so we call `name` to get them. And because it's the first key, we finally use `x.name[0]`. [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513049/get-all-keys-from-groupby-object-in-pandas) explains how to get keys from groupby.
   - `sale_type`: `x.name[1]` (idem as `Device_num`)
   - `1st_27dayssale`: we access the day from the date using `x.Date.dt.day` and it's compared with 27. Because we actually want the number of values, we perform `.sum` to count them : `(x.Date.dt.day <= 27).sum()`
   - `Tot_sale`: the number of row in the group e.g. `len(x)`
   - `last4dayscount`: `(x.Date.dt.day > 27).sum()` (idem as `1st_27dayssale`)
3. Using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` to remove the multi index from the groupby.

**Full code:**

```
# Be sure Date is a date type
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
print(df)
#    Device_num       Date sale_type
# 0        2344 2020-03-01        BP
# 1        2344 2020-03-12        BP
# 2        2344 2020-03-15        BP
# 3        2344 2020-03-20        BP
# 4        2344 2020-03-28        BP
# 5        3455 2020-03-10  Retailer
# 6        3455 2020-03-15  Retailer
# 7        3455 2020-03-31  Retailer


out = df.groupby(["Device_num", "sale_type", pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq="m")]).apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({"Device_num":  x.name[0],
                         "sale_type": x.name[1],
                         "1st_27dayssale": (x.Date.dt.day <= 27).sum(),
                         "Tot_sale": len(x),
                         "last4dayscount" : (x.Date.dt.day > 27).sum()})) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
#    Device_num sale_type  1st_27dayssale  Tot_sale  last4dayscount
# 0        2344        BP               4         5               1
# 1        3455  Retailer               2         3               1
```

Comment: i want to get the last three days sales to count on each month (not only march), how to get it? (ex: if u take Feb, last 4 days count(27/Feb/2020 - 29/Feb/2020).

Comment: @ShulazShan Please, instead of digging up an old subject, open a new one with what you tried and where you're stuck.