# Create multiple DataFrames based on given column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

There's probably a simple solution to this that I just couldn't find...
With the given DataFrame, how can I separate it into multiple DataFrames and go from something like:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>d ={'LOT': [102,104,162,102,104,102],'VAL': [22,424,65,4,34,6]}
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>>df

   LOT  VAL
0  102   22
1  104  424
2  162   65
3  102    4
4  104   34
5  102    6
```

to:

```
>>>df[0]
   LOT  VAL
0  102   22
1  102    4
2  102    6
>>>df[1]
   LOT  VAL
0  104  424
1  104   34
>>>df[2]
   LOT  VAL
0  162   65
```

With 3 distinct DataFrames
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple groupby. Let me see if I find a dupe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LOT': [102,104,162,102,104,102],
    'VAL': [22,424,65,4,34,6]
})

df = [x for _, x in df.groupby('LOT')]
```

---

**Ok, I found something**. However the answer seems overcomplicated so I'm gonna leave this here. 
Looks a lot like: [Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/)

Comment: That helps a lot! I'm not very familiar with that type of for loop, do you have any suggestions where I could go to learn more about it? [In particular, how it works having the x before "for" as well as after the comma?

Comment: How do we access the dataframes created ? Also if we want to group by 2 columns how will we access the dataframe ?

Comment: df which should be dfs and is an array so access by index.