# Pandas groupby with new column for each value

Tags: python, pandas

I hope the title speaks for itself; I'd just like to add that it can be assumed that each key has the same amount of values.
Online searching the title yielded the following solution:

[Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby)

Which supposed to be solving my problem, although it does not.
I'll give an example:

Input:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'a':['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','bar'],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Output:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'a':['foo','bar'],'b':[1,4],'c':[2,5],'d':[3,6]})
```

Intuitively, it would be a `groupby` function without an aggregation function, or an aggregation function that makes a list out of the keys.

Obviously, it can be done 'manually' using for loops etc., but using for loops with large data sets is very expensive computationally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `Series` or column `g`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last data cleaning by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with 
[`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
g = df1.groupby('a').cumcount()
df = (df1.set_index(['a', g])['b']
         .unstack()
         .add_prefix('new_')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
     a  new_0  new_1  new_2
0  bar      4      5      6
1  foo      1      2      3
```

Or:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('a').cumcount()
df = df1.pivot('a','g','b').add_prefix('new_').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
     a  new_0  new_1  new_2
0  bar      4      5      6
1  foo      1      2      3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely Solved this, only it raised another issue trying to sort each row:
"df_db[relevant_cols]=df_db[relevant_cols].apply(np.sort,axis=1)"
Raised: ValueError: cannot label index with a null key
I tried to reset index again, didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @user9548409 - One idea - is possible sorting before? Like `df = df.sort_values('b')` and then apply my solution?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm going to have some null values after the groupby that I need to fill 0s with, and only then sort.. sorting before will mess up the order.

If it matters, I used the first method(not the pivot function). Thanks again

Comment: @user9548409 - Ok, then use `df_db[relevant_cols] = np.sort(df_db[relevant_cols], axis=1)`

Comment: @user9548409 - tested with `df_db = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
print (df_db)

relevant_cols = ['B','C','E']
df_db[relevant_cols] = np.sort(df_db[relevant_cols], axis=1)
print (df_db)
`

Comment: Obviously, this one will work. It does not work after applying the groupby.. it messes up the indexes in some way. I tried to reset index yet still does not work

Comment: @user9548409 - If need working with data from question, use `df = df1.pivot('a','g','b')` and then `df = np.sort(df, axis=1)` and after sorting use `.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`. reason is very easy - after reset_index get first column non numeric, and `np.sort` should be problem. so if first sort and then reset_index then working only with numeric columns (`new_0  new_1  new_2`)

Comment: I really doubt it can't be tweaked into sorting after resetting index, but it really does work if you sort earlier.
Thanks a lot you were right and it is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach, using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) if column names are important:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','bar'],'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})

# Groupby 'a'
g = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)

# Construct new DataFrame from g
new_df = pd.DataFrame(g.values.tolist(), index=g.index).reset_index()

# Fix column names
new_df.columns = [x for x in ascii_lowercase[:new_df.shape[1]]]

print(new_df)

     a  b  c  d
0  bar  4  5  6
1  foo  1  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works. I used the other comment's method first, but after encountering sorting issues ("ValueError: cannot label index with a null key") I tried this one too and it raised the same error. 
Help will be appreciated solving this out as well. Googling didn't help so far.