# How to split a Dataframe into Sub-Dataframes by row index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, group-by

I have a function `foo()` with input parameter dataframe that counts each value large 1. So a dataframe 400x5 gets reduced to 1x5.

Now I have a dataframe like

```
Country    Value1    Value2
US         1         3
Uk         3         2
US         2         1
UK         5         5
```

The result could look like

```
Country    Value1    Value2
US         1         1 
Uk         2         2
```

My goal is to split the dataset by country and perform my `foo()`. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby) to split the dataset with `groupby()` but `groupby` gives me `tuples` back and not dataframes what is a problem since my `foo()` only eats dataframes. Does anyone have an idea how I can split my dataframe into dataframes and perform my funtion on them?

Comment: You can try: `df.groupby('country').apply(foo)`.

Comment: df.groupby(level=0).diff() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

data =  """Country    Value1    Value2
US         1         3
UK         3         2
US         2         1
UK         5         5"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df = df.groupby('Country').apply(lambda x: x.where(x > 1).count())
print(df)
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
         Value1  Value2
Country                
UK            2       2
US            1       1
```

Note, the countries are treated in a case sensitive manner, the Q contains mixed case,  the answer does not.