# Groupby Get Group For Loop

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, subset

I have a dataframe that I need to subset by the column measure name.
Measure_Group=measures.groupby('Measure'). I can get.group() like this CDC=Measure_Group.get_group('CDC') , but I have over 20 measures to subset. Is there a for loop or lambda function that I can use with the group by to subset all 20 column names with just one iteration instead of using the get.group multiple times

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691133/split-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groupby)

Comment: `measures[measures['Measure'].isin(list_of_20_measures)]`.