# How to Filter Year Data from Year column and make every year data a new Dataset from a single dataset

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

Here i don't understand how can i filter year and make every year data a new dataset from a single dataset.
My Dataset is -
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjO7M.png)

In this dataset, 2010 to 2020 (11 years) data is available.

And I need this dataset in this format-
[Output image. 2010 dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbyq.png)

[2011 Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfVSS.png)

So My output should be look like this in format.

```
path = r"C:\Users\krishna gupta\Downloads\Diwali\temp"
files = os.listdir(path)
b=[]
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(path+'\\'+file)
    df = df[df['SYMBOL'] == 'NIFTY']
    df = df[df['INSTRUMENT'] == 'FUTIDX']
    df['RANGE'] = df['HIGH'] - df['LOW']
    df['YEAR'] = df.TIMESTAMP.str[-4:]
#     df = (df.iloc[0])
#     display(df)
    b.append(df)
df = pd.concat(b)
df = df.sort_values(['YEAR','TIMESTAMP'])
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
del df['index']
df = df[df['YEAR'] == '2011']
df.head(5)
```

This is my code, And `df = df[df['YEAR'] == '2011']` here I can filter data this way, but I want to print the data frame by itself.

And I'm really sorry in advance if I'm not writing my question in the right format because I'm new on StackOverflow. and thanks in advance.

Comment: You could get a dictionary of dataframes keyed to year. `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('YEAR')))` Then each DataFrame could be accessed like `d['2010']` or `d['2011']`.

Comment: Was that the kind of thing you meant? Because if that solves the problem I'll close this as a duplicate of [Split pandas dataframe based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23691133/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes.